# Google maps shows grey grid on the device

Tags: google-maps

I develop an application for android phone. when you click the button a mapview appears on the screen. I am not having any problem on emulator. My app works on emulator fine. however, on the real android device(phone) I only see grey grid.I modified the parts which are related to internet permission or api key on the source code. I am pretty sure that the api key is correct and put it to the appropriate part.

http://codemagician.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/android-google-mapview-tutorial-done-right/

I implemented exactly the same steps which are explained in the link above, however maps stil does not work. I googled it a lot, people mostly say there should be a problem on the API key but I tried what is exactly explained in google develeopers page, still does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your GPS (If using), Also try to Zoom in/out a little. You might set zoom to very high/low value

Answer (score 0):

The only case here is might be with your API_KEY
or you set the zoom value very High, 
Here Is a tutorial [step by step for Google Maps](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)

Comment: I don't think problem is not API_KEY, but what ?  i m writing the code into command screnn(cmd). then i see md5 certificate fingerprint. i can get API_KEY from google. my app works on virtual device(emulator) well. however when i load the .apk of my app to my real android device, my map doesn't appear. there are only grey square grids on the screen. i can manage zoom control like zoom in or zoom out but i can't see any street any city any country. my android device has an internet connection. i can go to other internet website or app.

Comment: Actually the thing is the fact that I am doing every step of getting API_KEY correct(I followed the steps in the google's developer page). It is little bit confusing since everything seems to be correct. I am wondering other than API or internet permission, can there be any other reason?

Comment: No other reason in my mind, try to test the app in some other device, may b problem with that particular device, As you said that the app runs fine on Emulator